# Replacing keys when dict value is a list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file for which I want to remove the $oid and $date and replace the keys like in the example below:

```
import json

def key_replacer(dictionary):
    new_dictionary = {}
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        if k in ('$oid', '$date'):
            return v
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = key_replacer(v)
        new_dictionary[k] = v
    return new_dictionary
                

data = """{
"_id": {
"$oid": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
},
"description": "some text",
"startDate": {
"$date": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
},
"completionDate": {
"$date": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"
},
"videos":[{"$oid":"5ecf6cc19ad2a4dfea993fed"}]
}"""

info = json.loads(data)
refined = key_replacer(info)
new_data = json.dumps(refined)
print(new_data)
```

Output: `{"_id": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff", "description": "some text", "startDate": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff", "completionDate": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z", "videos": [{"$oid": "5ecf6cc19ad2a4dfea993fed"}]}`. It works the way I want until "videos". How could I remove the $ sign for the "videos" part and replace the key like it happens in the other cases? It doesn't get into the contents of the list and I assume this is the cause.

Comment: what will happen if there are more than 1 video in your input data, do you want to keep a list of ids?

Comment: @oskros There are cases when the list has indeed more elements. And in this case it would make sense to keep a list of ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original function doesn't account for the case where the dictionary value is a list. By accommodating for that, you will get the desired result

```py
def key_replacer(dictionary):
    new_dictionary = {}
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k in ('$oid', '$date'):
            return v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            v = key_replacer(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            tmp = []
            for itm in v:
                tmp.append(key_replacer(itm))
            v = tmp
        new_dictionary[k] = v
    return new_dictionary
```

NB: If the items in the list is not dictionaries the code will break, so be mindful of that